# Apache2 Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] for wild card SSL certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4

I am trying to configure Godaddy Wild Card Certificates on a Apache web server.I am getting the following error:

```
[Thu Jul 23 02:32:42.499991 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12293:tid 140626762094464] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 23 02:32:43.553475 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12529:tid 139774360311680] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/godaddy-ssl.conf:2)
[Thu Jul 23 02:32:43.553518 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12529:tid 139774360311680] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Thu Jul 23 02:35:23.466577 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12707:tid 139928471259008] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 23 02:35:23.466637 2015] [core:notice] [pid 12707:tid 139928471259008] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

My apache server configuration with redirection for http request to https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName saasm2m.com

   ServerAlias saasm2m.com *.saasm2m.com 
    ServerAdmin helloworld@gmail.com
     RewriteEngine on
     ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

My SSL certificate configuration is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin saasm2m.com
        ServerName saasm2m.com
        ServerAlias *.saasm2m.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/saasm2m.chained.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/saasm2m.key
         ServerAdmin helloworld@gmail.com
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have changed my ports.conf to add Listen 443 http

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen  443 http
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen  443
</IfModule>
```

Update:
If i use this configuration it throws a error :AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/6eba0aa5c1b8.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/website_ssl.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

I have enabled ssl module by using:sudo a2enmod ssl and activated server configuration files by using sudo a2ensite filename.
Can anyone point out how I can fix this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `SSLCertificateFile` configuration line in addition to the `SSLCertificateKeyFile` configuration file.

You have configured one of two options for CA certificates.  You may not need either.  This may be configured with the file that should be the `SSLCertificateFile`

GoDaddy provides documentation on i[nstalling your certificates.](https://www.godaddy.com/help/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache-centos-5238)  According to that the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt should be configured with the `SSLCACertificatePath` parameter.  This parameter is called `SSLCertificateChainFile` in Apache versions before 2.4.8.

Comment: I have tried adding SSLCertificateFile before it throws this error  AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down .I am using Godaddy certificates.They provided two files.6366fe3949c165bc.crt and gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt .Which file I have to refer in SSLCertificateFile.

Comment: @Tanmay See updates